# OpenStreetMap xml clarification - no image available

Tags: openstreetmap, osmarender

I am new to OSM.
I have the document https://trac.openstreetmap.org/browser/subversion/applications/rendering/osmarender6/osm-map-features-z14.xml?rev=10976
This document describe set of rules for certain zoom.

There are rules that uses an image (svg) objects, e.g:

```
    <rule e="node" k="waterway" v="lock_gate">
        <wayMarker k="waterway" class="canal-lock"/>
    </rule>
```

And there is CSS for canal-lock in the same file:

```
.canal-lock {
fill: none;
stroke: #ffffff;
stroke-width: 0.1px;
stroke-opacity: 0;
marker-mid: url(#canal-lock);
}
```

And finally, at the bottom of the document there is:

```
    <svg:marker fill="none" id="canal-lock" markerHeight="5.9px" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" markerWidth="5.9px" orient="auto" refX="1px" refY="5px" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.75px" stroke-opacity="1" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
        <svg:path d="M 1,0 L -2,5 L 1,10"/>
    </svg:marker>
```

My Question is, Where does the canal-lock image is obtained from. i could not find that svg on the site, and my map seems to not working well since its looking for this image.

Comment: osmarender development stopped in 2012, you should switch to a different [renderer](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering).

Comment: i am not using ismarenderer as a tool

Comment: But these rules are specifically made for osmarender. Each renderer has its own set of rules, its own set of symbols etc.